# If it has an emergency locator, what is the probability that it will be discovered?

Tags: probability

Okay so here's the question

> Seventy percent of the light aircraft that disappear while in flight
>   in a certain country are subsequently discovered. Of the aircraft that
>   are discovered, 60% have an emergency locator, whereas 90% of the
>   aircraft not discovered do not have such a locator. Suppose that a
>   light aircraft has disappeared. If it has an emergency locator, what
>   is the probability that it will be discovered?

Anndd here's **my** answer

[image: answer]

The answer to this question was, however, given as 93%. I don't understand how they got that answer and I was pretty confident in my solution. Can someone either tell me the answer given in the text is incorrect or what's wrong with my solution?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you have the second $0.7$ factor in the numerator in the last formula? You have $P(E \mid D) = 0.6, P(D) = 0.7$, so it should be $0.7 \cdot 0.6$ and not $0.7 \cdot 0.6 \cdot 0.7$. Without it the answer is indeed $0.93$.

Comment: I think I got confused with what I was doing in the denominator because for finding the probability that it _does_ have an emergency locator, we multiply 0.7 to 0.6. I guess I don't really get the difference between P(E|D) and the probability that it does have an emergency locator? Because then it that case shouldn't my denominator also just be 0.6 + (0.3)(0.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, you can think of $P(E \mid D)$ in the numerator as "given that you are already inside the $70 \%$ that has been discovered, what is the probability that inside that $70 \% $ it does have an emergency locator?" so you don't take $.7$ into account in the calculation, you only take $.6$.

You can also use the formula 
$$P(D \mid E) = \frac {P( D \cap E)}{P(E)}= \frac {(.7)(.6)}{(.7)(.6)+(.3)(.1)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's use a frequency table of a deterministic cohort of light aircraft that disappear.  Suppose there are $N = 100$ such aircraft.  As $70\%$ of these are discovered, this means $70$ aircraft belong in the group $D$, indicating that they are subsequently discovered, and $30$ aircraft belong in the group $\bar D$, indicating they are not discovered.

Among the $70$ discovered aircraft, $60\%$ have an emergency locator, so $$D \cap L = (70)(0.6) = 42$$ where $L$ represents the event that an aircraft has an emergency locator.  Thus there are $$D \cap \bar L = (70)(0.4) = 28$$ that were discovered but had no emergency locator.

Similarly, among the $30$ undiscovered aircraft, $$\bar D \cap \bar L = (30)(0.9) = 27$$ had no emergency locator; and $$\bar D \cap L = (30)(0.1) = 3$$ had an emergency locator.

We summarize the above in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & L & \bar L & \\ \hline D & 42 & 28 & 70 \\ \hline \bar D & 3 & 27 & 30 \\ \hline & 45 & 55 & 100 \end{array}$$

Therefore, given that an aircraft has an emergency locator--that is to say, is one of the $45$ aircraft in column $L$--the number of discovered aircraft is $42$, thus the proportion of such aircraft is $42/45 \approx 0.933$.

---

In the language of probability, where $D$ and $L$ are events, we are given $$\Pr[D] = 0.7, \quad \Pr[L \mid D] = 0.6, \quad \Pr[\bar L \mid \bar D] = 0.9,$$ and we wish to compute $$\Pr[D \mid L] = \frac{\Pr[L \mid D]\Pr[D]}{\Pr[L]}.$$  Then $$\Pr[L] = \Pr[L \mid D]\Pr[D] + \Pr[L \mid \bar D]\Pr[\bar D] = (0.6)(0.7) + (1 - 0.9)(1 - 0.7) = 0.45,$$ and $$\Pr[D \mid L] = \frac{(0.6)(0.7)}{0.45} = \frac{42}{45} \approx 0.933,$$ as we found using the deterministic cohort above.

Answer (score 1):

$P(D \mid E)$

$= P(D \cap E)/P(E)$

$= P(D \cap E)/P((E \cap D) \cup (E \cap \overline{D}))$

$= P(D \cap E)/\{P(E \cap D) + P(E \cap \overline{D})\}$

$= \{P(D) \cdot P(E \mid D)\}/\{(P(D) \cdot P(E \mid D)) + P(\overline{D}) \cdot P(E \mid \overline{D})\}$

$= (0.70 \cdot 0.60)/((0.70 \cdot 0.60) + (0.30 \cdot 0.10))$

$= 0.93$